# Query with multiple key and conditions

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have two keys, key1 and key 2, which sometimes don't exist.

I would like that :

- the posts which have a key 1 are classified according to the key 1,
- the posts which have a key 1 and a key 2 are classified according to
  key 1,
- the posts which do not have a key 1 but a key 2 are classified
  according to key 2,
- and after posts that do not have a key.

Here is one of the tests, but which did not give the expected result:

```
$query = new WP_Query([
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        ['key' => 'key1', 'compare' => 'EXISTS'],
        ['key' => 'key1', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'],
        ['key' => 'key2', 'compare' => 'EXISTS'],
        ['key' => 'key2', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'],
    ],
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
]);
```

Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: By "classified" you mean the order the posts should appear in?

Comment: Here you find all kinds of examples for your query: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/